# Exclude application from postgres logs

Tags: postgresql, configuration, logs

Currently on one of our dev servers we log everything what happend in database, but lots of traffic in is generated by patroni cluster and is not needed in further investigation. Is possibile to exclude application from postgres logs?

Something like "log from every application except 'patroni' and 'postgres'".

```
application_name="all -postgres -patroni"
```

Yes, i know, i can filter it later, but will be nice if this can be done before write anything to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to do this by user, but not by application name.  Does/can patroni log in as it's own user?

```
alter user patroni set log_statement to none
```

Comment: Good hint, patroni uses user postgres, but it also can be omitted.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, I still have logs full of information from the user postgres. :/

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe patroni turns it back on after completing the log on?